# Linux Alias with multiple and depending commands possible?

Tags: bash, alias

I've created some aliases that I use one after another. It's always depending whether the previous command succeeded.

Is it possible to use one alias for multiple commands, depending on the screen output? E.g.: When the output contains "fail" or "error" the next command should not be set.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, failure of a command is signalled by its non-zero exit status. In such a case, using `&&` solves your problem:

```
ls /nonexistent-file && echo This won\'t be printed
```

If you need to check the output, you can use `grep` and `||`:

```
echo fail | grep 'fail\|error' || echo This won\'t be printed
```

Don't forget to quote the alias content:

```
alias safe-ls='ls /nonexistent-file && echo This won'\''t be printed'
```

If you need parameters for the commands, you'll have to use functions instead:

```
safe-ls () {
    ls "$1" && echo This won\'t be printed
}
```

Comment: The already used "&&" helped me out here. One last logical question:
I have 4 commands - A,B,C,D. B is depending on RC=0 of A and D of RC=0 of C. How can I start them all with this dependencies? Can I use some kind of brackets?

Comment: You can run them as two sequences: `A && B; C && D`, or you can even run them in parallel with single `&`: `A && B & C && D`.